# How to easily add text to a wallpaper on Linux

Tags: linux, image-editing, annotations, image-manipulation

How can I easily add text and setup font parameters to a wallpaper on Linux ?

I've tried Shutter but it does not permit so enlarge the text to fill the wallpaper surface.

Comment: Will Gimp work?

Comment: @OleTange D'you know something easier to use ?

Comment: Will Krita work?

Answer (score 2):

Gimp should work. You can install with `sudo apt-get install gimp`. I can't think of any reason it would not work other than you are dealing with some weird proprietary file format in which case, just make a screenshot of the wallpaper and bring it up in gimp.

Comment: D'you know something easier to use ?

Comment: Doesn't get much eaiser than gimp. You could pay someone I suppose. Oh, there is ImageMagick, but the command line options to annotate an image will likely leave you with a headache.